# Find limit with sum using integration

Tags: integration, limits, summation, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm working on this problem:

> Find the limit
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=5n}^{7n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}
> $$

My initial thought is to turn it into an integral and work from there, but I'm not sure how to do this, especially since it contains $k=5n$.

Comment: Pull out $1/n^2$ and the terms become $\frac{1}{(k/n)^2 + 1}\frac{1}{n}$. So for fixed $n$, each term in the series is $\frac{1}{7^2 + 1}\le \frac{1}{(k/n)^2 + 1} \le \frac{1}{5^2 + 1}$. Now try to make it into an integral.

Comment: Okay so from that I can write the integral? With the limits 1/50 and 1/26?

Comment: Not quite. See @user's answer for it all spelled out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us set

$$S_n=\sum_{j=5n}^{7n}\frac{n}{j^2+n^2}.$$

Observe that

$$S_n=\sum_{j=0}^{7n}\frac{n}{j^2+n^2}-\sum_{j=0}^{5n}\frac{n}{j^2+n^2}+\frac{n}{(5n)^2+n^2}=7\sum_{j=0}^{7n}\frac{7n}{(7j)^2+(7n)^2}-5\sum_{j=0}^{5n}\frac{5n}{(5j)^2+(5n)^2}+\frac{1}{26n}.$$

Set

$$a_{N,s}=\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{N}{(sj)^2+N^2}$$

so that

$$S_n=7a_{7n,7}-5a_{5n,5}+\frac{1}{26n}.$$

Observe now that

$$a_{N,s}=\frac{1}{s}\cdot\frac{s}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{N}j\right)^2+1},$$

and so

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}a_{N,s}=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^s\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}=\frac{\arctan(s)}{s}.$$

It follows that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\arctan(7)-\arctan(5).$$

Answer (score 5):

Your idea is fine, indeed we have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=5n}^{7n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=5n}^{7n} \frac{1}{\left(\frac kn\right)^2+1}=\int_5^7\frac1{x^2+1}dx=\arctan 7 - \arctan 5$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the limit as a difference of two limits
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=5 n}^{7 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}= \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{7 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}-\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{5 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}+  \underbrace{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{(5 n)^2+n^2}}_{=0} 
$$
For the first limit, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{7 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}
= & \lim _{7 n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{7-0}{7 n} \sum_{k=1}^{7 n} \frac{1}{\left(0+\frac{(7-0)k}{7n}\right)^2+1}\\=& \int_0^7 \frac{1}{1+x^2} d x\\=&\arctan 7
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly for the second limit, we have $$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{5 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}=5\arctan 5
$$
We can now conclude that
$$\boxed{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=5 n}^{7 n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2} = \arctan 7-\arctan 5 \;}
$$

Replacing $5$ and $7$ by $a$ and $b$ respectively yields the general result
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=an}^{b n} \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}= \arctan b-\arctan a \; $$